# How to submit partly HTML code thru a webform to an SQL Server Database?

Tags: asp.net

I've got this simple table.  One field inside it is called **Content** with the **Nvarchar(max)**.

If I edit that field directly in the database using SQL Server Management, adding the following text below, it stores it fine.

Text:

```
Do you open the menu at a restaurant ever expanding multi-cultural tourist hub, Chinatown has a lot to offer to meet your culinary desires, from China and beyond.<br /></br>This tour will be the first in a series the food.
```

However if I try to submit the same text above using an ASPX page webform to the database, I get the error below, I assume because of the 2 `<br />` code

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (tbTourDetails="...nd beyond.
> This tour...").

How can I get around this so I can have a webform that submit partly HTML to my database?

Regards
Tea

Comment: do a html encode before storing and html decode while retreiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to store html code, you need to add requestValidationMode="2.0" to the httpRuntime configuration section of the web.config.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Now encode it before storing:

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

And decode it for displaying as a text:

```
Label1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dbValue);
```

**References:**
[HtmlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)
[HtmlEncode, HtmlDecode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)